# How to prove that if $x=\sup A$, then there is a convergent sequence to x of the elements of A.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How to prove that if $x=\sup A$ , then there is a convergent sequence to $x$ of the elements of $A$.

Comment: What is your definition of $\sup A$?

Comment: sup A is the smallest of the upper bounds of A.

Comment: Great. Focus on those two terms. "Smallest", and "upper bound". Think about them, and what they mean together. It's an upper bound, there is no smaller number that is also an upper bound, and there is no upper bound that is also smaller. That should answer the question you asked under the other answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $a_n\in A$ which satisfies $x-\frac{1}{n}<a_n\leq x$, this easily follows from the definition of a supremum. Such a sequence $a_n$ obviously converges to $x$.